# Use angularjs function return in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a angularJS function which returns a value and would like to create an if statement in javascript. I've tried the following but so far no luck.

**AngularJS:**

```
            $scope.orderTotal = function(index) {
                    var orderTotal = 0;
                    angular.forEach($localStorage.items, function(items) {
                        orderTotal += items.quantity;
                    })
                    return orderTotal;
            };
```

**Javascriptfile.js:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  document.write(orderTotal());
}
```

or:

```
if (orderTotal() > 10) { 
  document.write(orderTotal());
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this and what would it look like?

Comment: Not without access to the controller so you can get to the scope. It's defined on the scope and so it's not in the global namespace.

Comment: If you can place `orderTotal` in a service instead of a controller, you can put the `write` call in angular's "run" block and inject the service. For example, `angular.module('myapp').run(function (myService) {document.write(myService.orderTotal});`...

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to do too many things outside of angular and should be using the framework properly

Answer (score 0):

[RvdM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5925970/rvdm) - "Because adding and removing classes on divs is something I do with javascript I need to have some variables defined in angularjs available in javascript. **Are there better ways to accomplish this?**"

Yes, to add and remove classes on elements in AngularJS, use the `ng-class` directive.

From the Docs:

> ### ngClass
>
> The `ngClass` directive allows you to dynamically set CSS classes on an HTML element by databinding an expression that represents all classes to be added.

-- [AngularJS ng-class Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

Comment: How does this answer the question? The OP is asking how to insert text derived from Angular into the DOM during `document.ready` (he really should just be using `{{orderTotal()}}`. He isn't doing anything with classes.

Comment: For the conditional part he should be using `ng-if` or `ng-show` (or add the condition to the expression) since he's trying to insert the value and not just style an existing value.

Answer (score -1):

You *can* - I'd question why, but oh well. You can use `angular.element` and `.scope` to get the current scope your function is contained in.

For example, say your above function was inside the controller `MyController`

```
<div id="controller" ng-controller="MyController"></div>
```

The JS you'd use is:

```
var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("controller")).scope();
```

`scope` now has access to all scope methods:

```
var total = scope.orderTotal();
```

Comment: I'm not sure the controller/scope is guaranteed be fully defined by the time `document.ready` is fired.

Comment: @AlvinThompson -- Might not be - not sure on that one. You can always use the universal JS fix and wrap it in a `timeout` :D

Comment: I'm saving data in an array defined with angularJS so part of the logic is in angularJS but would like to change some div classes based on the values. Because adding and removing classes on divs is something I do with javascript I need to have some variables defined in angularjs available in javascript. Are there better ways to accomplish this?

Answer (score -2):

the DOM :

```
<div id="mycontroller" ng-controller="mycontroller"></div>
```

In jquery you do this and it will access that controller and call that function

```
var orderTotal;
 $('#mycontroller').load = function(){
     orderTotal = angular.element('#mycontroller').scope().orderTotal();
 }
```

If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed
Here you go :)

Comment: Same problem as the other answer: the controller/scope is not guaranteed be fully defined by the time `document.ready` is fired.

Comment: Edited. Then simply wait when the controller is ready with the .load() function

Comment: That only waits until the DOM element is loaded (`document.ready` does the same except waits until **all** DOM elements are loaded). It doesn't wait until the scope is constructed.

Comment: that'll wait until the DOM element $('#mycontroller') is loaded. You were questionning wether the controller/scope wouldnt be fully defined before calling this method, this way you do know that it'll be fully defined.

Comment: That is not guaranteed. More specifically, the DOM element will be there but Angular may not have have called the function that creates the scope and defines `orderTotal` yet.

Comment: Can you backup your statement with any proof ? Either you're assuming that the load() function get executed before the elements is loaded, either you don't get what it does. The callback will be executed as soon as the $('#mycontroller')  will be done loading, it'll be done loading once angular will render the HTML and angular will render the HTML once it's done defining the scope

Comment: You're not listening (err...reading). As I said, you **are** guaranteeing that the element is created, but nothing you've done guarantees that the `orderTotal` function will be defined by the time you're calling it. The function is defined by Angular. The `load` event is pure HTML/javascript which knows nothing about angular. In order to guarantee that the function is defined you need to check with Angular in some way.

Comment: 1.Creation

The root scope is created during the application bootstrap by the $injector. During template linking, some directives create new child scopes. 

2.Watcher registration

During template linking directives register watches on the scope. These watches will be used to propagate model values to the DOM.

First it create the scope, then it renders. There's a plenty documentated doc for Angular, i suggest you to read it.

Comment: ...and application bootstrap happens **after** the document is loaded, since it needs to scan the elements to find/compile any directives.

Comment: It does not know anything about angular, it'll just get executed when the HTML is done loading. The HTML will not even be rendered until Angular finishes settings scopes and start to render the HTML, therefore  once the HTML is rendered ( and before the load() method gets called ) angular has already set up the scopes and other variable as required

Comment: From your last statement, I think you're confusing `document.load` with `document.ready`.

Comment: There is no `load` event on elements other than images or iframe not to mention that `$('#mycontroller').load =function(..` would never even execute